# Node.js Cluster module vs Microservices

Tags: node.js, microservices, scalability

They both solve the same issue - scalability. When to use which?

And is there a point to integrating cluster API for node app running inside a docker container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not really equivalent. Microservices solve an organizational and code management problem, scalability in a very dynamic way, reducing tight coupling, and keeping bugs isolated to one microservice). `cluster` solves scalability in a very limited way, by spinning out cluster workers on the same machine. If you have one large app and generally scale vertically (by increasing the amount of computing power your hosts have), `cluster` is great. If not, breaking things down int services (or further down into microservices) is also great.

You can also do both (your second question), for example running Node apps in containers on Kubernetes, where the Node apps use `cluster`. Depending on how your containers get run and how many vCPUs they're allocated, it may or may not have any effect, but it's only a couple lines of code so it doesn't hurt to add it.